# Occur at / with or something else

Tags: prepositions

I have a sentence where I need to add the preposition to occur, and I also need to know why it is so.

> Ragpicker's disease occurred (preposition) individuals who handled rags that were woven with contaminated animal fibers.

Answer (score 1):

**occur in** is the correct way of expressing this meaning.

**occur with** and **occur at** are both grammatically correct, and this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=occur%20in%2C%20occur%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coccur%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coccur%20with%3B%2Cc0) indicates that they do occur in sentences.

If you look at actual instances, you will see that **occur with** is usually used when two things occur at the same time, for example:

> Do any other symptoms **occur with** the cough?

Likewise, **occur at** is usually used when something occurs at a particular time or place, for example:

> Figure 18.3 shows the respiratory and cardiovascular changes that **occur at** birth, beginning with the first breath.